# Guardar respuesta HTTP en una variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

La verdad ya llevo varios días con esto.

Tengo una respuesta **HTTP** el cual me retorna lo siguiente:

```js
public comprobante:Comprobante = new Comprobante();
public personas:any[] = []

getComprobante() {
    this.comprobanteService.getMovimiento(47455).subscribe((result) => {
        this.comprobante = result.data;
        let persona = {
            "nombres":result.data.cliente_nombres,
            "id":result.data.cliente_id
        }

        this.personas.push(persona)
        console.log(result)
        console.log(this.personas) //ME RETORNA NULL
    });
}
```

Esto es lo que me retorna:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "caja_estado": "1",
    "caja_id": "758",
    "cliente_id": "190",
    "cliente_nombres": "OSWALDO MARRON CHURA",
    "nro_comprobante": "0000256"
  }
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getComprobante()
    console.log(this.comprobante.cliente_id) // Me retorna null
    console.log(this.personas) // Me retorna null
}
```

1.- En la consola `console.log(this.comprobante.cliente_id)` simplemente me retorna `null` y cuando ejecuto `console.log(this.comprobante)` me muestra supuestamente el objeto ya llenado con sus datos como corresponde, pero siempre con ese mensaje "This value was evaluated upon first expanding. It may have changed since then."

2.- El *array* `personas` tambien me retorna `NULL` o un *array* vacío. No se llena con el nuevo objeto que lo estoy creando.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para poder utilizar esta variable y el objeto en lo sucesivo?, al parecer se está ejecutando todo de golpe y no secuencial y no espera a que se termine de completar esa función `(getComprobante())` y continue con lo demás. He probado con `async` `await` en `getComprobante()` y nada.

Como sería la manera correcta para poder hacerlo con ¿async await? u otro método.

Comment: El problema es que intentas acceder a un elemento que es un [*observable*](https://angular.io/guide/observables) cuando el mismo aún no ha recibido datos. Tal como tienes escrito el método `getComprobante()`, el mismo no devuelve absolutamente nada y además llamas a `console.log` inmediatamente después de llamar a este método, lo cual es un error en el manejo de los observables.

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar, entonces cual sería la manera correcta para llenar y poder trabajar esas variables `comprobante` y `personas` con la respuesta que retorna mi `http`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso vamos hacer uso de `async/await`, recuerda que para utilizar `await`, debes retornar una promesa, en este caso convertimos tu observable en promesa usando `toPromise()`. El `ngOnInit` también debe tener la palabra `async` para poder esperar a que `getComprobante` termine.

```
async getComprobante() {
    const result = await this.comprobanteService.getMovimiento(47455).toPromise();
    this.comprobante = result.data;
    let persona = {
       "nombres":result.data.cliente_nombres,
       "id":result.data.cliente_id
    };

    this.personas.push(persona);
    console.log(result);
    console.log(this.personas);
}

async ngOnInit() {
    await this.getComprobante();
    console.log(this.comprobante.cliente_id);
    console.log(this.personas);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió de mucho.